# display a PDF from cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I can load a pdf in cloudinary but i can't display it. I tried with :

```
<%= cl_image_tag worker.cv.path, width: 1000, height: 1000,crop: :fill, format: :jpg %>
```

Renders in

```
<img width="1000" height="1000" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dgl9juzps/image/upload/c_fill,h_1000,w_1000/v1498033370/owpbctm8yi8pbwsxt3wz.pdf.jpg%22"  alt="Owpbctm8yi8pbwsxt3wz.pdf">
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks for help

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the expected outcome, what does the template render return?

Comment: I can't see the pic, it prints a string and the icon a of an image...

Comment: Could you post a rendered tag as an code example? Are you sure, that cloudinary supports these features for pdf? It seems to me that you probably cannot use an image tag to display a pdf without converting it to an image first.

Comment: Have you had a look at http://cloudinary.com/cookbook/convert_pdf_to_jpg

Comment: Yes i tried with this but it doesn't work : here is my code : <%= cl_image_tag worker.cv.path, width: 1000, height: 1000,crop: :fill, format: :jpg %>

Comment: Best to edit the question. Do not try to put code in the comments.

Comment: I mean the rendered tag. What is the output in the rendered html

Comment: this is the rendered html : Owpbctm8yi8pbwsxt3wz.pdf

Comment: No the whole image tag, otherwise it's not much use...

Comment: Roland je vois que tu es Suisse, peux tu m'expliquer en français ce dont tu as besoin stp? merci

Comment: Salut Tana. C'est difficile de voir ou le problème est, si on ne voit pas ou le faute pourait être. J'aimerais bien voir tout le image tag come `<img src='....' widht.... >` Parce que je pense le probleme est que demande a cloudinary un truc, que n'existe pas.

Comment: <img width="1000" height="1000" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dgl9juzps/image/upload/c_fill,h_1000,w_1000/v1498033370/owpbctm8yi8pbwsxt3wz.pdf.jpg" alt="Owpbctm8yi8pbwsxt3wz.pdf">

Comment: Voila, désolé pour l'incompréhension en EN ;)

Comment: Je viens de mettre le code a jour et j'ai essayé en transformant le pdf en jpg comme dans la doc cookbook de cloudinary mais rien....

Answer (score 0):

The rendered link has two problems:

```
<img width="1000" height="1000" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dgl9juzps/image/upload/c_fill,h_1000,w_1000/v1498033370/owpbctm8yi8pbwsxt3wz.pdf.jpg%22"  alt="Owpbctm8yi8pbwsxt3wz.pdf"> 

// src = "http://res.cloudinary.com/.../owpbctm8yi8pbwsxt3wz.pdf.jpg%22"
```

1. The trailing " from the %22
2. and the file extension is .pdf.jpg instead of just .jpg

The link works if you just call:

http://res.cloudinary.com/dgl9juzps/image/upload/c_fill,h_1000,w_1000/v1498033370/owpbctm8yi8pbwsxt3wz.jpg

So maybe you should only pass the filename without extension to the helper.

Comment: Thanks Roland, the problem is that i should call users downloaded pdf...How could i pass this differents filenames without helpers?